# Shadow-Dom Role Behaviour <a> tag without href

Tags: typescript, shadow-dom

I'm new by working with the shadow Dom. Unfortunately, I do have a strange behaviour:

I do have an ionic angular application which styles a text in the form of a link:
(simplified)

```
<a href="${ifDefined(this.href)}">link</a>
```

my test checks the existence by following:

```
const link = screen.getByShadowRole('link');
```

as the href is set via a variable, it could be removed which leads to the case, the role gets removed too - which leads the test to fail. It seems the  tag does lose the Role:Link by not having a href.
I could not find much information about this behaviour - is that a bug, expected or why is the role removed from the tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I could not find much information about this behaviour - is that a bug, expected or why is the role removed from the tag?

It's specified behavior. An `a` element without an `href` isn't a link, so it doesn't have that role. From [the HTML standard for `a`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element):

> **Accessibility considerations:**
>
> If the element has an `href` attribute: [for authors](https://w3c.github.io/html-aria/#el-a); [for implementers](https://w3c.github.io/html-aam/#el-a).
>
> Otherwise: [for authors](https://w3c.github.io/html-aria/#el-a-no-href); [for implementers](https://w3c.github.io/html-aam/#el-a-no-href).

If you follow the "for authors" links there, you'll see that an `a` element with an `href` has `role="link"`, but an `a` without an `href` has `role="generic"`.

Comment: Thank you - that explains it very obvious